# Manually deciding locking mode in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, locking

In MSSQL, when a lock is acquired with a statement, the locking mode is decided by the engine not by the programmer. Is there a way to force the engine to use a specified Locking Mode (i.e. Row Lock)?

Answer (score 8):

Sure, there are plenty of [table hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table), like:

- `PAGLOCK`
- `ROWLOCK`
- `TABLOCK`
- `TABLOCKX`

However, you should use these with extreme caution. There are very few cases where the average programmer knows better than the engine, and forcing hints [can cause more problems than they solve](https://littlekendra.com/2016/02/04/why-rowlock-hints-can-make-queries-slower-and-blocking-worse-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Though I am trying to do a ROWLOCK, the engine is not respecting my choice and would still go and lock the keys instead.

Comment: @Hasan Just because you *say* `ROWLOCK` doesn't mean SQL Server can actually *do* it. In many cases your row locks will actually escalate to a table lock (skipping page altogether). What is the query? What is the table structure? How many indexes? This seems like a different question altogether than the one you've posted here. Create a new question with details and someone can probably explain to you why your row locks are not being obeyed.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I'm not particularly interested in knowing about the escalation inner policies and rulings. I just wanted to know if there is such a way to force the engine to use s specific mode, but apparently there is none.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in SQL Server you can do this with [Table Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table)..

Example:

```
UPDATE Production.Product  
WITH (TABLOCK)  
SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 1.10  
WHERE ProductNumber LIKE 'BK-%';  
GO
```

Comment: Though I am trying to do a ROWLOCK through table hints, the engine is not respecting my choice and would still go and lock the keys instead.